# Iterate over possible values of interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Let's say we have typescript interface declaration like this

```
export interface MyInterface {
  foo: "a" | "b" | "c"
}
```

Is it possible to get array of possible values for the property foo? That is ["a", "b", "c"].

Comment: You cannot get runtime value from the type. Is this interface controlled by you or external?

Comment: Only other way around - define the array, then you can extract and use its type

Comment: It's controlled by me. I know that I can define a custom type/enum like FooType and then define interface foo: FooType but that's boilerplate I tried to avoid.